# Make fixed image size in cards which are looped in *ngFor in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an array of cards like this which will be fetching images from the urls of different sizes. How can I make it consistent in all the cards.

[image]

I was doing this for styling the image and its container.
**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
    <img class="card-image" [src]="url" />
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 250px;
  max-height: auto;
  float: right;
}

.card-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use width, drawback is image will not look good, solution is svg images

```
.card-image {
   width: 75px;
   height: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got the card width fixed/consistent, so if I understand your query correctly, you want the images inside these cards to be of same width and height.

The styling class for the images you are using is card-image.

If you set these 2 properties in that class, you should be able to get a consistent/fixed size for the images in all the cards, something like-

```
  .card-image {
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
  }
```